# Unable to plot chloreopath worldmap with Vincent in iPython

Tags: python, ipython, vega, vincent

Trying to draw a shaded worldmap in Vincent (similar to county example in the Map Data Binding section [here](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#map-data-binding)).  My code doesn't throw errors, but produces a solid color map (ie- all countries are blue).

I have thematic data describing each country (where countries are identified as iso3 codes).  A toy version of my data is:

```
import pandas as pd
import vincent
import numpy as np

iso3 = ['USA','CHN','BRA']
x = [50,100,150]

data = pd.DataFrame({'iso3': iso3, 'x': x})
```

I stripped the id codes out of the world country map from the vincent map repo and create a dataframe that matches information in the data to the id codes from the world map json (which are iso3 codes):

```
import json
with open('world-countries.topo.json', 'r') as f:
get_id = json.load(f)

new_geoms = []
for geom in get_id['objects']['world-countries']['geometries']:
    new_geoms.append(geom['id'])

amounts = np.zeros((shape(new_geoms)[0]))
j=0
for i in list(new_geoms):
    this_data = data[data.iso3==i]
    if shape(this_data)[0]>0:
        amounts[j] = np.asscalar(this_data['x'])
    else:
        amounts[j] = 0
    j=j+1

map_data = pd.DataFrame({'iso3' : new_geoms, 'x': amounts})
```

map_data looks good, has 177 entries (equal to the number of polygons (countries) in world-countries) with no NaN's for x and matches where they should be, although four of the id codes are equal to -99 (these are places like Kosovo that have no formal iso3 codes). Finally, I plot the data using Vincent:

```
world_topo = r'world-countries.topo.json'
geo_data = [{'name': 'countries',
             'url': world_topo,
            'feature': 'world-countries'}]

mapx = vincent.Map(data=map_data, geo_data=geo_data, projection='mercator',  scale=150, 
              data_bind='x', data_key='iso3',
              map_key={'world-countries':'geometries.id'}, brew='YlGnBu')
mapx.marks[0].properties.enter.stroke_opacity = vincent.ValueRef(value=.25)
mapx.display()
```

Again, this code runs without error, but the map has no thematic shading based on the value of x.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use this for map_key:

`map_key={'countries':'id'}`